# C++ Statement can be simplified

Tags: c++, if-statement, intellij-idea, simplify

Apologies for the lame question. I am using Intellij Clion Student licensed version for my C++ curriculum. As a part of implementing an UnsortedList class, we had to write a method `isInTheList` to see if an element is present in the array. The class implementation goes as

```
bool UnsortedList::isInTheList(float item) {

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (data[i] == item) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, the ide shows a coloured mark at `data[i] == item` with a popup saying

```
Statement can be simplified less... (Ctrl+F1) 
This inspection finds the part of the code that can be simplified, e.g. constant conditions, identical if branches, pointless boolean expressions, etc.
```

For a previous method to check if the list if empty, I used the following simplified form instead of if-else statement.

```
bool UnsortedList::isEmpty() {
    return (length == 0);
}
```

However, with iteration involved now, I cannot come up with a simplified statement in the former. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Unrelated but `isInTheList()` will not work as per your expectation.The `return false` should be outside the loop.

Comment: @GauravSehgal it's very much related. OP does not find the simplified version because they missed that the second `return` executes just after the `if` :)

Comment: Oops, my bad, logical error. I guess that was the problem with the IDE itself. Once that was moved outside the loop, the error vanished. Can you write it as the answer? I will accept it. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Comment: By the way, CLion doesn't just _say_ that the expression can be simplified. It also offers to simplify it for you. If you had allowed it to do so, you would probably have realised your mistake.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Indeed, I realized. Thank you awesome stackoverflow community :)

Comment: i hope you also think about that floats are not exact values if it has been involved in any kind of calculation. so if (data[i] == item) may then fail, instead subtract from each other and check is smaller than lambda.

Comment: opinionated nitpick: parentheses around operands of `return` statements are (usually) unnecessary, cluttered, and can (in unusual cases like that of `decltype(auto)`) lead to different, possibly counterintuitive results.

Comment: @AndersK. Never knew that. Infact, we haven't reached that point yet, if it is in out curriculum. Can you point to any relevant links for further reads?

Comment: @file2cable yes here : http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Thank you @AndersK. This is why I love stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Fix**

Your `return false` should be moved outside off the `for` loop.

---

Because you accidentally put it inside the `for` loop, this iteration never execute for the second time.

So your IDE thinks the `for` loop is pointless, and suggests you to simplify it to:

```
return data[0] == item;
```

This obviously isn't what you want. So really this is just a one-line shift to make it right.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use STL?

```
inline bool UnsortedList::isInTheList(float item) {
    return std::find(data, data+length, item) != data+length;
}
```

[`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) returns an iterator pointing to the element if it's found, or an iterator equal to one-past-last item (i.e. exactly the second argument passed) if nothing is found. You can use a simple equality check to decide if one is found.

Comment: It would be useful if you could show how to return a boolean as the OP intended.

Comment: While this does answer _"I cannot come up with a simplified statement"_, note that OP also added _"in the former"_, which to me indicates that they want an answer that fixes that code, rather than just suggesting a different way to do it, which admittedly would be superior if it was complete.

Comment: Shouldn't the `==` be `!=`?

Comment: I'd add that, if `data` is an array of static size, then `std::begin(data)` and  `std::end(data)` et al. produce far clearer and more maintainable code than `data+length`. Of course, if it's a dynamic array, then they aren't usable, and what you have is the best we can do. I'm also not sure that adding `inline` here produces any benefit, and it doesn't seem like the place to have that debate anyway.

Comment: STL is now C++ standard library. STL is dead since 15 years at least.

Answer (score 2):

You are actually returning after one iteration in your loop. That's the remark of your compiler.
Your code could be simplified by easy write this:

```
bool UnsortedList::isInTheList(float item) {

    if (length != 0) {
        return data[0] == item;
    }
}
```

Note, that this is still undefined behavior (UB). You do not have a `return` in all of your execution paths.
If your list is empty, you never enter the loop, which results in an UB, because there is no `return` statement, but the function has to return a `bool`.

I think, your intention was, to write something like this.

```
bool UnsortedList::isInTheList(float item) {

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (data[i] == item) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Move the `return false;` out of your `for loop` and you will be fine (still there are better ways to implement this, but that's another topic).